# Overriding class methods. Print output including NONE

Tags: python-3.x, class, derived-class, overriding

Issue with output with derived print_all class method when inserted under class PetData. My output is including NONE before ID: 4444. Why?

```
class AnimalData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.full_name = ''
        self.age_years = 0

    def set_name(self, given_name):
        self.full_name = given_name

    def set_age(self, num_years):
        self.age_years = num_years

    # Other parts omitted

    def print_all(self):
        print('Name:',  self.full_name)
        print('Age:', self.age_years)


class PetData(AnimalData):
    def __init__(self):
        AnimalData.__init__(self)
        self.id_num = 0

    def set_id(self, pet_id):
        self.id_num = pet_id

    # FIXME: Add print_all() member method

    ''' Your solution goes here '''

    def print_all(self):
        print(AnimalData.print_all(self), 'ID:', self.id_num)

user_pet = PetData()
user_pet.set_name('Fluffy')
user_pet.set_age(5)
user_pet.set_id(4444)
user_pet.print_all()
```

Output:

Name: Fluffy
Age: 5
None ID: 4444

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
''' Your solution goes here '''

def print_all(self):
    AnimalData.print_all(self)
    print('ID:', self.id_num)
```